# Impossible to close Textfield box during app running

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm developing an iphone app.

When my app running (during test on my computer), i need to change the value in a textfield box but when it s done, the keyboard stays, and i can't get back to the app, i'm trapped !

How could i close the keyboard and go on ?

Many thanks

Comment: Please search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227859/hide-keyboard-on-touch-outside-of-textfield

Comment: Cos it's been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338967/hiding-the-keyboard-when-uitextfield-loses-focus

Answer (score 1):

Set the delegate to `UITextField`, then implement UITextField delegate methods
this will enable the user to use the Keyboards Return Key to hide the keyboard.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

If you are using a UIButton then

```
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

If you want to resign the keyboard when the user touch the screen outside the UITextField then use the following code which will work on all the `UITextField` in the `UIView`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews){
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder]) {
            [txt resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];    
}
```

Comment: @user2971617 If you find the answer useful please accept it as right answer which will help to remove this question from unanswered question list.